# Set of convergence of $\sin(n_k x)$ Big rudin chapter 4 question 10

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(n_k)$ be increasing positive integers, let $E$ be the set of $x$ s.t. $\sin(n_k x)$ converges, show $\mu(E) = 0$

The hint said use the cosine double angle identity and that the integral of $\cos(nx)$ and $\sin(nx)$ is zero over $E$

So, I tried to use this previous result, and letting the limit function be $l$, I can show the integral of $l$ is zero and $l^2$ is half the measure of $E$.

The hint also said show $2\sin^2(n_k x)$ converges to $1$ almost everywhere

Comment: Why don't you update the question to contain some of what you have tried to solve the problem. Maybe looking at the results from the chapter would help put it in context for everyone. Maybe some neighboring problems could be helpful to jog your memory...

Answer (score 0):

we can consider the set of $x \in E$ s.t. $2\sin^2(n_k x) $ converges to a number less than $1$ and integrate the double angle formula to get that the limit of $2\sin^2(n_k x) $ is $1$ almost everywhere. Now consider the set where $\sin(n_k x)$ converges to $1/2$, by standard arguments we can show this is measure zero, I'll elaborate when I get back.